# while statement with initializer

Tags: c++, scope, initialization, c++17

C++17 has [selection statements with initializer](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17)

```
status_code foo() {
    if (status_code c = bar(); c != SUCCESS) {
      return c;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to write a `while`-loop and a variable with a *scope limited* to the loop and *initialized only once* before the first iteration.

```
// fake example, doesn't compile, is doable in many ways
while (bool keep_trying = foo(); keep_trying) {
    // do stuff
    if (something)
        keep_trying = false;
}
```

Is there anything for this in C++17 or maybe coming in C++2a?

Comment: `while (bool keep_trying = foo(); keep_trying)` would be the same as `for (bool keep_trying = foo(); keep_trying; )` So in a sense you've always had it. :)

Comment: And if you incorporate the `if (something) keep_trying = false` part, then your full loop would be `for (bool keep_trying = foo(); keep_trying; keep_trying = !something) { /* do stuff */ }` (assuming `somthing` isn't using local variables defined inside the loops block-statement).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I want `while (SomeClass inst = init(); inst.someBoolMethod()) {doSomethingWith(inst);}` that executes `SomeClass inst = init()` before every iteration — that's certainly not what `for` does.

Comment: @Sasha Well that's a *little* different from this question. So unless you're happy with `for (SomeClass inst = init(); inst.someBoolMethod(); inst = init()) { doSomethingWith(inst); }` you need to ask an actual question for alternatives.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, the real alternative I use is `for(;;) {SomeClass inst = init(); if (!inst.someBoolMethod()) break; doSomethingWith(inst);}}` (sadly, C++ doesn't have a dedicated infinite-looping statement, so I need to use `for (;;)`). Still I would like to see `while (SomeClass inst = init(); inst.someBoolMethod()) {doSomethingWith(inst);}` in the language too, of course. (But that is not a question, so I can't ask it.)

Comment: @Sasha That's essentially equivalent to the `for` loop in my comment. If you have problem with it, pleasa ask an actual question (with more details about why you can't use the corresponding `for` loop) to get more detailed answers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I think that your loop is slightly: (1) less beautiful, because it requires to repeat `inst = init()` twice (and a real expression we denote here as `init()` may be quite long); (2) less versatile, as it requires type of `inst` to be non-const and assignment operator to be declared for `SomeClass` (which is not always true). However, as I've said above, there's no question to ask (a side-comment is not a question).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[P0305R1](https://wg21.link/p0305r1), the paper that introduced the `if` statement with initialization, explains this pretty well.  From the [Proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html#proposal) section:

> There are three statements in C++, if, for and while, which are all
>   variations on a theme. We propose to make the picture more complete by
>   adding a new form of if statement.
>
> ```
> while (cond) E;
> for (init; cond; inc) E;
> if (cond) E;
> if (cond) E; else F;
> if (init; cond) E;         (new!)
> if (init; cond) E; else F; (new!)
> ```

(table simplified)

Note that `while (cond)` corresponds to `for (init; cond; inc)`.  Also, from the [Discussion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html#discussion) section:

> It is often said that C++ is already complex enough, and any
>   additional complexity needs to be carefully justified. We believe that
>   the proposed extension is natural and unsurprising, and thus adds
>   minimal complexity, and perhaps even removes some of the existing
>   differences among the various control flow statements. There is
>   nothing about the local initialization that is specific to loop
>   statements, so having it only on the loop and not on the selection
>   statement seems arbitrary. Had the initializer form of the if
>   statement been in the language from the start, it would not have
>   seemed out of place. **(At best one might have wondered why for is not
>   also spelled while, or vice versa.)**

Comment: I did read the paper (but very quickly) and I was surprised to not find any mention of the comma operator with which you could pretty much express more or less the same thing than an if statement with initializer... I was about to use the comma operator before thinking about the if with initializer. comma operator is pretty much under used... imho...

Answer (score 13):

"While statement with initializer" = "For statement without updation"

And you have always had a `for` loop regardless of the version of the language.

Comment: They are totally different. In the for statement, the initialization happens only the first time, but the author wants it to happen on every iteration. Which is a good idea, because it would remove the ugly 
while ((err = read (fd, buf, size)) != -1) syntax

which would be equivalent of:

while (int err = read (fd, buf, size); err != -1)

Comment: @Nuclear Anent that part of the Question — "write a `while`-loop and a variable with a *scope limited* to the loop and *initialized only once* before the first iteration", it certainly does not sound like the author wants the initialization to happen on every iteration. If, instead, you are seeking for it or landed up on this page by the latter, you may check out the option to ask a different question where there is more space to add further details and clarify your problem.