# Why we can have a semicolon in if but not in while loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, c++17, c++20

Why can I do this:

```
if (int result=getValue(); result > 100) {
}
```

but cannot do this:

```
while (int result=getValue(); result > 100) {
}
```

Why discriminate against `while`? A condition is a condition. Why `while` cannot evaluate it like `if` can?

In order to achieve the desired behavior with `while`, I'd have to implement it this this way:

```
int result = getValue();
while (result > 100) {
    //do something
    result = getValue();
}
```

Comment: why do you expect them to be same or even similar? They express different things, if not one of them could / should be removed

Comment: Probably no one proposed the change to while() when the change was made to if() in c++17 Related: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

Comment: Does [while statement with initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986173/7582247) answer your question?

Comment: BTW, the way to write the last snippet would be `while(int result; result = getValue() && result > 100) {}`. I'm not sure you're describing the same semantics with the while-with-initializer.

Comment: @cigien, I don't think it will work if the desired value of `result` is 0, because it won't check the second condition.

Comment: @armanali Aah, yes good point. You'd have to write it twice then.

Comment: _I don't want to do a loop._  But `while` **is** a loop construct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because we already have a while-loop-with-initializer. It's spelled:

```cpp
for (int result=getValue(); result > 100;) {
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do a loop. Let me edit my question.

Comment: @armanali if you don't want a loop, then why do you use `while`?

Comment: Your edit doesn't change anything. `for` still does the job.

Comment: @cigien, thank you. For some reason `for` didn't come to my mind since the code looks better with `while`. I usually use `for` when I need a counter.

Comment: I still think `while` should support it, but for my purpose I can use `for` as well. It will do the job.

Comment: @armanali counter in four is optional and you can use those statement for anything

Comment: @armanali Why do you want `while` to support this? It's a lot of work to add a feature to the language, and this has no apparent benefit.

Comment: @cigien, it's just a matter of convenience, that's all. For the same reason `if` supports it.

Comment: You may be able to submit a proposal to add this in 2023 although I have doubts it would be accepted.

Comment: Wouldn’t the proposed syntax want to evaluate the *init-statement* every iteration?

Comment: I don't think that just because I can do it in a `for` loop it is a good enough reason for me not to be able to do it in a `while` loop. Any `while` loop can be turned into a `for` loop. Does that mean `while` can be deprecated?

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 reasons I can think of for not adding this syntax.

1. There is a perfectly suitable construct, namely the `for` loop, that can be used for exactly this purpose.
2. Adding any feature to the language is a lot of work, and a very strong case needs to be made for such a proposal. Given the first point, I don't see this happening.
3. In my opinion this is the most important one: If this feature were added to the language (let's say for a convenient syntax, or something like that), then it can essentially never be removed from the language. This means that the `while (;)` syntax is forever banned, and there could very well be some other semantics that we would like to express using such a syntax, and giving up this option is not something that should be done without careful thought.