# Can declarations and conditions be separated in while loops?

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements, declaration, c++20

I'm trying to write something like this in C++20 mode.

I see that C++17 can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836867/c-variable-declaration-in-if-expression) for `if` conditionals.

```
char *o = ch;
char *a = ch;
while (o = strstr(o, "||"), a = strstr(a, "&&");
            o != nullptr && a != nullptr)
{
}
```

Is there any comparable syntax for while loops doing assignment?

Comment: `if(o != nullptr && a != nullptr) break;` is much more readable.

Comment: The problem I'm having is if `o` or `a` is a `nullptr` it exits the `while` loop.

Comment: @ZeroPhase what do you *want* it to do? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to do work in `while`, until `o` and `a` are nullptrs

Comment: Perhaps you want `o != nullptr || a != nullptr`, which would run the loop until *both* `o` and `a` are nullptrs?

Comment: Apparently [they considered it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59985550/while-statement-with-initializer) but chose not to. `if` and `for` can have initialization statements, `while` cannot. Shrug.

Comment: assignment inside while loop = for loop: `for (; o = strstr(o, "||"), a = strstr(a, "&&"); o != nullptr && a != nullptr) {}`

Answer (score 2):

You might use `for` loop

```
for (auto* o = strstr(ch, "||"), a = strstr(ch, "&&"); // init-statement
     o && a; // Condition
     /*o = strstr(o, "||"), a = strstr(a, "&&")*/) // iteration_expression
{
// ...
}
```

Comment: It's just frustrating that it's not consistent in C++ currently. I'm sure in C++ 27 we'll have while loops with my syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

C++ already supports compact assign and compare expressions, since assigning returns the updated value. What you describe can be written as:

```cpp
char const *o = ch;
char const *a = ch;
    
while ((o = strstr(o, "||")) != nullptr && 
       (a = strstr(a, "&&")) != nullptr) { 
  /*...*/ 
}
```

or more succintly (since comparing with `nullptr` is just checking a truthy value):

```cpp
char const *o = ch;
char const *a = ch;
    
while ((o = strstr(o, "||")) && (a = strstr(a, "&&"))) { 
  /*...*/ 
}
```

the only caveat is that due to short-circuiting, the second assignment only happens when the first condition evaluates to true. Here's an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/114fcf60607146d7).

Answer (score -1):

Ended up going with.

```
char *o = strstr(ch, "||");
char *a = strstr(ch, "&&");
while (o != nullptr || a != nullptr)
{
    o += 2;
    if (o) o = strstr(o, "||");
    if (a) a = strstr(a, "&&");
}
```

That other syntax would have been more succinct for this. Wish C++ would allow that syntax for all loops and conditionals.

Comment: What's the deal with `o += 2;`? If `o` is null to begin with, then what? And if by incrementing it it points to garbage, then what?

Comment: Have to increment `o += 2` past `||` in the string or it keeps looping forever. I can put in the condition when needed.